# Validate language code for Wikimedia languages

Tags: sh, sparql, wikimedia, wikidata-query-service

I have a shell script that uses Wikidata Query Service (WDQS) to get required data. The SPARQL query that run WDQS takes input parameter language code.

Is there a way that I can check in shell script if the input language code is a valid Wikimedia language code as the first column data in below link
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Wikimedia_language_codes/lists/all

Comment: You mind sharing what **"the given string input"** is -- or am I just missing something? Are you talking about the `/etc/locale.gen` formats? (e.g. `fo_FO.UTF-8 UTF-8`)?  If so, then `if grep -q "$input" /etc/locale.gen; then printf "valid locale\n"; else printf "locale not found\n"; fi`

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I wanted.

Comment: That shows you even a blind squirrel finds a nut every now and then. That was a swinging *guess* at what you needed. Glad it helped.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I modified the question because the previous question looks general and simple.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Wikimedia language codes are different from ISO 639 codes (which are used in `locale.gen` AFAIK).

Comment: http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/SPARQL#WikiMedia_Languages  has a query having ISO code + Wikimedia country code + number of speakers that might be giving you another perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These codes are possible values of [`wdt:P424`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P424). From the [property proposal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Property_proposal/Archive/5#P424):

> — Is there a big difference to ISO 639-1?
>   — Many of them are the same as ISO, but it is not done in a consistent way. Some language codes have two letters, some three, and a few even more. And there are also a few cases where it is completely different (als: ISO: tosk Albanian, Wikimedia: Alemannic).

You could retrieve all these codes using the following simple SPARQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?code { [] wdt:P424 ?code } ORDER BY ?code
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcode%20%7B%20%5B%5D%20wdt%3AP424%20%3Fcode%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fcode)

In fact, the list you have linked to is periodically generated by a bot. The full query [is](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Help:Wikimedia_language_codes/lists/all&action=edit):

```sql
SELECT ?item ?c
(CONCAT("{","{#language:",?c,"}","}") as ?display)
(CONCAT("{","{#language:",?c,"|","en}","}") as ?displayEN)
(CONCAT("{","{#language:",?c,"|","fr}","}") as ?displayFR)
{
  ?item wdt:P424 ?c .
  MINUS{?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q14827288} #--exclude Wikimedia projects
  MINUS{?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q17442446} #--exclude Wikimedia internal stuff
}
```

You could:

- paste the list of valid codes into your script, *or*
- preload the list at your script startup, *or*
- execute an `ASK` SPARQL query at every user input.

I would prefer the third option:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter language code:"
read code
request="curl -g -s https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=ASK{?lang%20wdt:P424%20\"$code\"}"

if $request | grep -q "true"; then
    echo "Valid code";
else 
    echo "Invalid code";
fi
```